# Unhandled Exception: A Products was used after being disposed

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using `MultiProvider` and I get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: A Products was used after being disposed. Once you have called dispose() on a Products, it can no longer be used.
```

Here is my main.dart file. What is wrong with this structure?

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Auth(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
          update: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => Products(
            auth.token,
            auth.userId,
            previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items,
          ),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Cart(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Orders>(
          update: (ctx, auth, previousOrders) => Orders(
            auth.token,
            auth.userId,
            previousOrders == null ? [] : previousOrders.orders,
          ),
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer<Auth>(
        builder: (ctx, auth, _) => MaterialApp(
          title: 'MyShop',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
            accentColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            fontFamily: 'Lato',
          ),
          home: auth.isAuth
              ? ProductOverviewScreen()
              : FutureBuilder(
            future: auth.tryAutoLogin(),
            builder: (ctx, authResultSnapshot) =>
            authResultSnapshot.connectionState ==
                ConnectionState.waiting
                ? SplashScreen()
                : AuthScreen(),
          ),
          routes: {
            ProductDetailScreen.routeName: (ctx) => ProductDetailScreen(),
            CartScreen.routeName: (ctx) => CartScreen(),
            OrdersScreen.routeName: (ctx) => OrdersScreen(),
            UserProductsScreen.routeName: (ctx) => UserProductsScreen(),
            EditProductsScreen.routeName: (ctx) => EditProductsScreen(),
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue, I see the question has been submitted a while back. Were you able to get any answers?

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with this structure. (At least I couldn't figure out what was wrong) It pretty much seemed like a bug, because I got no error in different projects with this structure.

Comment: I get the exact same error with a pretty similar setup. Have you found any solution meanwhile?

Answer (score 23):

use yourProvider.value
Instead of Create

```
  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: products[index],
        child: ProductItem(),
      ),
      itemCount: products.length,
    );
```

Comment: Thanks! I added the type of the object to work better. `ChangeNotifierProvider<Servico>.value(...)`

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the same error and I resolved it by:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<"Provider name">.value(value:<PassedValue>);
```

It seems ChangeNotifierProvider creates an instance of the provider and when its work is done dispose() method is called and therefore, that instance is cleared with ChangeNotifierProvider.value, that's not the case and we are able to re-use the earlier created instance.

Here are the official docs: https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this for example:

```dart
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => ChangeNotifierProvider<EntryPermitViewModel>.value(
            value: EntryPermitViewModel(),
            child: const EntryPermitScreen(),
          ),
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can fix it

```
GridView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10),
          itemBuilder: ((context, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value( //   <--
               
                value: productsItems[i],
                child: ProductItem(),
              )),
          itemCount: productsItems.length,
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

add delay for Products provider in ProductsOverviewScreen;

```
@override
void initState() {
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) {
    Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).fetchAndSetProducts();
  });
  super.initState();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add Products Provider to providers: [] above proxy providers as the definition of Auth Provider like the following:

```
providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<Auth>.value(
                          value: Auth(),
     ChangeNotifierProvider<Products>.value(
                          value: Products(),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
      update: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => Products(
        auth.token,
        auth.userId,
        previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items,
      ),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<Cart>.value(
      value: Cart(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Orders>(
      update: (ctx, auth, previousOrders) => Orders(
        auth.token,
        auth.userId,
        previousOrders == null ? [] : previousOrders.orders,
      ),
    ),
  ],
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');
```

In your drawer where you called `logout`.
This will fix that
Thank you..