# A product was used after being disposed once you have called dispose() on a product, it can no longer used

Tags: flutter

i am getting error after going back
A product was used after being disposed once you have called dispose() on a product, it can no longer used.
my code is written down

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import './screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import './screens/products_overview_screen.dart';
import '/provider/products.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (ctx) => Products(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Ram Shop',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
          accentColor: Colors.deepOrange,
          fontFamily: 'Lato',
        ),
        home: ProductsOverviewScreen(),
        routes: {
          ProductDetailScreen.routeName: (ctx) => ProductDetailScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i tried searching for solution but didn't found any . please check my code and tell me what's wrong.

Comment: Post more code, the error is not being caused by the code you posted, but by something else happening to products on another screen. Are you using setState after navigator has been popped? Or there's a notify listener happening in the background, and the page is being rebuilt at the same time it's being popped.

Comment: Does this answer you question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59657953/unhandled-exception-a-products-was-used-after-being-disposed?